# how to sort a scipy array with order attribute when it does not have the field names?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2d scipy array(The oigion is the one color channel of an rgb image). I want to find the specific occurance of an element. I can use

```
   np.argsort(arr)
```

to do the job.

But the problem is that I want to do it in a specific order along axis. The scipy example for doing this is as follows

```
   x = np.array([(1, 0), (0, 1)], dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')])
   np.argsort(x, order=('x','y'))
```

In the above example they specified the name of the filed and the type. After that they used the argument "order" to specify the order of sorting.

In my case I don't have the filed names... How can I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, suppose you have an ordinary numpy array:

```
In [34]: x = np.array([(1, 0), (0, 1)])
```

You can view it as a so-called [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy.doc.structured_arrays/) by using `view`:

```
In [35]: y = x.ravel().view(dtype=[('x', x.dtype), ('y', x.dtype)])
```

Now you can use `np.argsort` on `y` with the `order` parameter:

```
In [36]: np.argsort(y, order=('x','y'))
```

Comment: I have tried the following example and it gives the indexes 0 always
`x = np.array([[0, 3], [2, 2],[5, 5],[0,0],[6,3]]),
y = x.view(dtype=[('x', x.dtype), ('y', x.dtype)]),
np.argsort(y,order=('y','x'))` returns

`array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])`

Comment: `y` should be of shape (5,), not (5,1). Try it with `y=np.array([(0, 3), (2, 2), (5, 5), (0, 0), (6, 3)], dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')])`.

Comment: by doing this the view is not created... Anyways my data is in the form which i had wrote... If you could please specify the solution in the same format.
Thanks

Comment: @Shan: Ah, now I see. I should have used `ravel` before `view`. I've edited my answer to show what I mean.